# How can I typeset an algorithm with columns as in CLRS (Introduction to Algorithms)?

Tags: algorithms

In  *Introduction to Algorithms*, by Thomas Cormen, there are some algorithm like in this image. With one column for the code, one for the cost and one for the times.

I searched a lot, but I didn't find how to do it.

[image]

Comment: I suspect this was done with 3 columns, no rows (other than heading and body), in a tabular, one of the standard algorithm packages in the code column,  and forced linebreaks in the cost and times columns.
But that is a guess.

Comment: I guess Cormen did use [the `clrscode` package](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/clrscode/clrscode.pdf), since he mentions: _This document describes how to use the
`clrscode` package in LaTeX2ε to typeset pseudocode in the style of Introduction to Algorithms, Second edition, by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein (CLRS)_

Comment: Using `\>` is mentioned in the manual of `clrscode`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what I'd do, if I were not to use `clrscode`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}

\newcommand{\TITLE}[1]{\item[#1]}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{$/\!/$ \parbox[t]{4.5cm}{\raggedright #1}}
% ugly hack for for/while
\newbox\fixbox
\renewcommand{\algorithmicdo}{\setbox\fixbox\hbox{\ {} }\hskip-\wd\fixbox}
% end of hack
\newcommand{\algcost}[2]{\strut\hfill\makebox[1.5cm][l]{#1}\makebox[4cm][l]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \TITLE{\textsc{Insertion-Sort}$(A)$}
    \algcost{\textit{cost}}{\textit{times}}
  \FOR{$j=2$ \TO $A.\mathit{length}$
    \algcost{$c_1$}{$n$}}
  \STATE $\mathit{key} = A[j]$
    \algcost{$c_2$}{$n-1$}
  \STATE \COMMENT{Insert $A[j]$ to the sorted sequence $A[1..j-1]$}
    \algcost{$0$}{$n-1$}
  \STATE $i = j-1$
    \algcost{$c_4$}{$n-1$}
  \WHILE{$i>0$ \AND $A[i]>key$
    \algcost{$c_5$}{$\sum_{j=2}^{n} t_j$}}
  \STATE $A[i+1]= A[i]$
    \algcost{$c_6$}{$\sum_{j=2}^{n} (t_j-1)$}
  \STATE $i = i-1$
    \algcost{$c_7$}{$\sum_{j=2}^{n} (t_j-1)$}
  \ENDWHILE
  \STATE $A[i+1] = \mathit{key}$
    \algcost{$c_8$}{$n-1$}
  \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Please, notice a few things:

1. There are three widths (in centimeters) that may need tweaking.
2. The costs of `for` and `while` statements are inside the brackets and there must not be any space between them and the closing bracket.  This is a bit fragile.  The same for `if` and all other block statements.
3. The cost of line 3 is displayed next to the first of the two lines, not the second (as in the original).  It was easier like this, but I think I also prefer it.

This answer takes the opposite route from Jubobs's answer, which is using the `clrscode` package.  If you prefer to use `clrscode`, I'm sure you'll find the way to properly use `|>` for tabbing the extra columns, although it's not well documented.  Also, it may be preferable for other reasons too, if you want your algorithms to look exactly like those in the book.

---

[image: result]

Comment: Pretty nicely done.

Answer (score 10):

(Only a partial answer)

Cormen used his [`clrscode` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clrscode?lang=en) for the second edition of CLRS, but a "beefed-up" version of it, called [`clrscode3e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clrscode3e?lang=en), for the third edition, from which the *Insertion Sort* algorithm in your screenshot is taken. For more details, see [this](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/).

The code for typesetting the algorithm (but *without* the "cost" and "times" columns) can be found on page 6 of the [`clrscode3e` documentation](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/clrscode3e.pdf). The latter makes no mention of how to typeset columns. Besides, the package's source code doesn't seem to provide any (undocumented) mechanism for that.

However, Cormen's `codebox` environment is based on a `tabbing` environment; perhaps there is something to be done there, but I'm not that familiar with `tabbing`...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{clrscode3e}

\begin{document}

\begin{codebox}
\Procname{$\proc{Insertion-Sort}(A)$}
\li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
\li     \Do
            $\id{key} \gets A[j]$
\li         \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence
                $A[1 \twodots j-1]$.
\li         $i \gets j-1$
\li         \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li             \Do
                    $A[i + 1] = A[i]$
\li                 $i \gets i-1$
                \End
\li         $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
        \End
\end{codebox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know which package is used for the fourth edition ?

Comment: @alper I'm only learning now, thanks to your comment, that a 4th edition has been released! Thanks. So no, I don't know yet what they use in the new one.

Comment: I belive the algorithms are same but mainly they add some colors

Answer (score 2):

There is the CLRS package, code name "clrscode3e", the description of the package as well as the `.sty` file are available in the web-site: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrscode/, you can easily download the `.sty` file and also read the description.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{clrscode3e}

\begin{document}

\begin{codebox}
\Procname{$\proc{Insertion-Sort}(A)$}
\li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
\li     \Do
            $\id{key} \gets A[j]$
\li         \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence
                $A[1 \twodots j-1]$.
\li         $i \gets j-1$
\li         \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
\li             \Do
                    $A[i + 1] = A[i]$
\li                 $i \gets i-1$
                \End
\li         $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
        \End
\end{codebox}
\end{document}
```