# Whats the best way to typeset an algorithm with columns, as in CLRS (Intro to algorithms)

Tags: algorithms

In Introduction to Algorithms, by Thomas Cormen, there is some algorithm with cost and time columns for asymptotic analyses. There is a similar post already, where a member named nickie provides a method of how to it, but I am running box overflow problems when I try to add IF statements, I am wondering if the "ugly hack" can be modified to include them. Nickies code and image below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}

\newcommand{\TITLE}[1]{\item[#1]}

\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{$/\!/$ \parbox[t]{4.5cm}{\raggedright #1}}

% ugly hack for for/while

\newbox\fixbox

\renewcommand{\algorithmicdo}{\setbox\fixbox\hbox{\ {} }\hskip-\wd\fixbox}

% end of hack

\newcommand{\algcost}[2]{\strut\hfill\makebox[1.5cm][l]{#1}\makebox[4cm][l]{#2}}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]

  \TITLE{\textsc{Insertion-Sort}$(A)$}

    \algcost{\textit{cost}}{\textit{times}}

  \FOR{$j=2$ \TO $A.\mathit{length}$

    \algcost{$c_1$}{$n$}}

  \STATE $\mathit{key} = A[j]$

    \algcost{$c_2$}{$n-1$}

  \STATE \COMMENT{Insert $A[j]$ to the sorted sequence $A[1..j-1]$}

    \algcost{$0$}{$n-1$}

  \STATE $i = j-1$

    \algcost{$c_4$}{$n-1$}

  \WHILE{$i>0$ \AND $A[i]>key$

    \algcost{$c_5$}{$\sum_{j=2}^{n} t_j$}}

  \STATE $A[i+1]= A[i]$

    \algcost{$c_6$}{$\sum_{j=2}^{n} (t_j-1)$}

  \STATE $i = i-1$

    \algcost{$c_7$}{$\sum_{j=2}^{n} (t_j-1)$}

  \ENDWHILE

  \STATE $A[i+1] = \mathit{key}$

    \algcost{$c_8$}{$n-1$}

  \ENDFOR

\end{algorithmic}

    enter code here

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add the link to the similar question to your question. Show the code of an algorithm and how you tried to solve the issue in LaTeX. Please explain your issue better ...

Comment: "I don't yet have the reputation points to ask questions" - You just asked a question. You have not the reputation for answering. Please add a link and code or image of what you want.

Comment: Is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239697/how-can-i-typeset-an-algorithm-with-columns-as-in-clrs-introduction-to-algorith/239859#239859) the answer by @nickie that you refer to?

Comment: This structure is more typical of algorithms than of what's defined by `amsmath`, so I've retagged it.